# How to set my regex to return in only one line?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

My input information can be: "abc1-abc-ab-0/1/2" OR "abc1-abc-0/1/2". I need a help to get my return variable in one line. In my regex code, I'm gettint two lines of maches. Can anyone help me?

```
[root@server]# echo "abc1-abc-ab-0/3/7" | grep -oP '^(([a-zA-Z0-1]){4})-(([a-zA-Z]){3})|-(([a-zA-Z]){2})' 
abc1-abc
-ab
```

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: you've got a pipe char in the regex between the 3 and 2 char blocks. Do you want that?

Comment: The final solution with the help of the user "Trygve Flathen" is:
`    [root@server]# echo "abc1-abc-ab-0/3/7" | grep -oP '^(([a-zA-Z0-1]){4})-(([a-zA-Z]){3})|-(([a-zA-Z]){2})' | xargs echo | tr -d ' '
    abc1-abc-ab`

Thanks all!

Comment: Probably the regex that is the problem, isin't it?

Comment: If you use @sln's revised regex, you get the desired result directly (no need for additional commands). If you don't, a modification of @glennjackman's approach simplifies matters (no need for `xargs`): `echo "abc1-abc-ab-0/3/7" | grep -oP '^(([a-zA-Z0-1]){4})-(([a-zA-Z]){3})|-(([a-zA-Z]){2})' | tr -d '\n'` (outputs without a terminating `\n`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to collect output of a command on one line:

```
echo $( command )

command | xargs echo
```

Answer (score 2):

The newlines are due to `grep -o`. I would pipe that through `| tr '\n' ' '`

Answer (score 1):

Probably need this regex

```
 #  ^(([a-zA-Z0-1]){4})-(([a-zA-Z]){3})(-(([a-zA-Z]){2}))?

 ^ 
 (                             # (1 start)
      ( [a-zA-Z0-1] ){4}            # (2)
 )                             # (1 end)
 -
 (                             # (3 start)
      ( [a-zA-Z] ){3}               # (4)
 )                             # (3 end)
 (                             # (5 start)
      -
      (                             # (6 start)
           ( [a-zA-Z] ){2}               # (7)
      )                             # (6 end)
 )?                            # (5 end)
```

Comment: +1 for recognizing that the OP's multi-line problem goes away when reformulating the regex. To put it together: `echo "abc1-abc-ab-0/3/7" | grep -oP '^(([a-zA-Z0-1]){4})-(([a-zA-Z]){3})(-(([a-zA-Z]){2}))?'`.